# Changing current mysql database in a procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

For our system we are using multiple databases with the same structure. For example when we have 1000 customers, there will be 1000 databases. We've chosen to give each customers his own database, so we can delete all his data at once without any hassle.

Now I have to update the database structure several times a year. So I began to write a stored procedure which loops through all schemas. But I got stuck with executing a dynamic USE statement.

My code is as follows:

```
DECLARE V_SCHEMA VARCHAR(100);
SET V_SCHEMA = 'SomeSchemaName';
SET @QUERYSTRING = CONCAT('USE ', V_SCHEMA);
PREPARE S FROM @QUERYSTRING;
EXECUTE S;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE S;
```

When I execute this code I get an error which says `Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`. So I assume that I cannot change the active database in a procedure.

I have searched the internet, but the only thing I found was creating a string of each alter query and prepare/execute/deallocate it. I hope there is a better solution for this. I could write a shell script that loops through the schemas and executes a SQL file on them, but I prefer a stored procedure that takes care of this.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I use the latest stable version of MySQL 5.6

Comment: you probably need to rethink the way you update all these schema. Perhaps you can write a script in another language (eg. PHP, Perl, Python), which will emit the `USE`  and stored proc queries.

Comment: another possibility is to make one stored proc per schema, with the schema name hardcoded. You will have to generate all the stored procs, which means that you might have to resort to an external script there too.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I think the following solution fits best in my situation.

I create a SQL script for each upgrade without the schema names in it. Then I will iterate over the schemas with PHP and execute the SQL file with a shell command:

`mysql --user=myUser --password=myPassword --host=hostName companySchemaName < upgrade.sql`

It will be harder to debug the output, but I think this is the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are some known databases, then try to write a CASE.

Otherwise, do not execute USE statement using prepared statements; instead, build other statements (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ...) with full name - `<database name> + '.' + <object name>`, and execute them using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your structure changes into a stored procedure in a temporary schema, you can do this within a Workbench SQL window.

You can build your iteration script using a query against the `information_schema`, e.g.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('USE ',schema_name,'; CALL tmp.Upgrade')
                    SEPARATOR ';\n') AS BldCode
FROM   information_schema.schemata
WHERE  schema_name NOT IN
       ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql', 'sakila', 'world', 'tmp')
```

Since you cannot execute this as a prepared statement, you can copy the  SQL result into a new SQL window, and run that.

Please note that the structure changes stored procedure would need to operate on the current schema, rather than specifying schemas.